# min results in NA after group_by then mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

Consider this toy dataset

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

data = tibble(
  code = rep(paste0("CODE", 1:3), each = 2),
  visit = rep(factor(c("VS", "V2"), levels = c("VS", "V2")), 3),
  value = runif(6)
) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(code = "CODE4", value = 1))
```

```r
r$> data
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  code  visit value
  <chr> <fct> <dbl>
1 CODE1 VS    0.266
2 CODE1 V2    0.372
3 CODE2 VS    0.573
4 CODE2 V2    0.908
5 CODE3 VS    0.202
6 CODE3 V2    0.898
7 CODE4 NA    1
```

(values are random so your output will surely change)

The following code runs as expected:

```r
r$> data %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(ratio = value / lag(value))
# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   code [4]
  code  visit value ratio
  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 CODE1 VS    0.266 NA   
2 CODE1 V2    0.372  1.40
3 CODE2 VS    0.573 NA   
4 CODE2 V2    0.908  1.59
5 CODE3 VS    0.202 NA   
6 CODE3 V2    0.898  4.45
7 CODE4 NA    1     NA
```

Whereas adding the `min` operator makes the ratio value return NAs everywhere.

```r
r$> data %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(ratio = min(value / lag(value), 1e4))
# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   code [4]
  code  visit value ratio
  <chr> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 CODE1 VS    0.266    NA
2 CODE1 V2    0.372    NA
3 CODE2 VS    0.573    NA
4 CODE2 V2    0.908    NA
5 CODE3 VS    0.202    NA
6 CODE3 V2    0.898    NA
7 CODE4 NA    1        NA
```

What is the reason for this behaviour ?

EDIT: Now I understand that the `min` in `mutate` is called in a vectorized manner, so because there are NAs in some rows, the NA value is returned to all rows, hence the use of `pmin` solves the problem.

Comment: Check the arguments of the `min` function. If one element is NA, then `min` returns NA. See argument `na.rm`.

Comment: I found the solution to use `pmin` instead of `min` but I expect `min` to behave correctly on `dbl` arguments

Comment: This does not give the expected output I provide in the first example.

Comment: @paulduf you have used `runif` without `set.seed`.  So, the values will be different when someone tries

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is below the mention "The following code runs as expected:". I added a seed to allow to reproduce. Now I understand that mutate applies the function in a vectorized manner and calling `min` with at least one NA assign NA to all entries, and this is why `pmin` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `na.rm = TRUE` in `min` - by default it is `FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(code) %>%
   mutate(ratio = value / lag(value), 
   ratio = case_when(complete.cases(ratio)
      ~ min(ratio, 1e4, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  code  visit value  ratio
  <chr> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 CODE1 VS    0.362 NA    
2 CODE1 V2    0.309  0.855
3 CODE2 VS    0.636 NA    
4 CODE2 V2    0.265  0.417
5 CODE3 VS    0.948 NA    
6 CODE3 V2    0.884  0.933
7 CODE4 <NA>  1     NA
```

Comment: It indeed returns the right ratio when visit is V2, but does not give the expected output I provide in the first example. I expected `ratio` to remain NA when visit is VS. Moreover, there are side-effects when visit is NA.

Comment: @paulduf that logic was not stated in the post i.e. visit is V2

Comment: It is because visit is set as factors with levels, isn't it ? Is the `lag` method circular ?

Comment: @paulduf `v1 <- 1:5; lag(v1)#[1] NA  1  2  3  4`

Comment: @paulduf can you use `set.seed` with expected output so that it is more clear.  I was thinking that the issue is with the whole column filling NA (as lag returns the first element as NA by `default`)

Comment: @paulduf when you take `min`, it returns a single value for each group.  Perhaps you need `pmin` or replicate the `min` output? i.e. `data %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(ratio = pmin(value / lag(value), 1e4))`

Comment: @paulduf can you try the update in the post

Comment: Indeed `pmin` is what I was looking for, thank you